# Image Magick slow drawing

Tags: c++, imagemagick

I am trying to draw a bunch of lines on image using Image Magick library (Magick++ API) and the total execution time appears to be quite a large.

Are there any ways to optimize IMagick drawing performance?

```
int SIZE = 700, LINES_NUM = 6000;

Image outputImage(Geometry(SIZE, SIZE), Color("white"));

for (int i = 0; i < LINES_NUM; i++) {
    outputImage.draw(DrawableLine(lines[i].x1,lines[i].y1,
                                  lines[i].x2,lines[i].y2));
}
```

Comment: Is ImageMagick really the only library you can use? It's known for being ubiquitous, not speedy.

Comment: @tadman No, I am ok to switch to anything. What would you recommend for the best performance?

Comment: I've had really good luck using Node.js with a headless canvas package for bulk image processing, something that leverages the very robust and ridiculously fast `<canvas>` element code in Chrome/WebKit. For a pure C++ version you might try using OpenGL which is even faster than that, but in practice more clumsy and tricky to use bare. There's also OpenGL-derived drawing libraries.

Comment: I have found from experience that the first time one tries to draw in ImageMagick, it may be slow, since it has to load some delegate libraries. Is the timing the same if you run your command multiple times? Are you on a shared server?

Comment: @fmw42 Yes, I tried it multiple times but result was the same.

Comment: On some systems, multi-threading does not work well on some commands. Have you tried compiling ImageMagick without OpenMP or set the thread limit to 1 ( convert -limit thread 1 .... )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to avoid repeat `Magick::Image.draw` calls.

```cpp
std::vector<Magick::Drawable> drawList;
for (int i = 0; i < LINES_NUM; i++) {
    drawList.push_back(DrawableLine(lines[i].x1,lines[i].y1,
                                    lines[i].x2,lines[i].y2));
}
outputImage.draw(drawList);
```

Also ensure that the ImageMagick libraries have been compiled with `OpenMP` support. If your going for speed, and not quality, I would recommend recompiling without High Dynamic Range Imagery `--enable-hdri=no`, and a low Quantum depth `--with-quantum-depth=8`.

Comment: I have tried exactly the same code for bulk rendering as you suggest but performance was nearly the same.